# How does the death order work in "Final Destination 3"?

Tags: final-destination, final-destination-3

So McKinley causes Wendy's death. But according to the order McKinley should have died first. And then Wendy. But Wendy intervened in McKinley's death. That's why McKinley is alive. Otherwise he would be dead. Then how does the clue works?

Comment: In short - everybody dies in FD series .

Comment: yeah. I know that. but I am unable to understand why this discrepancy has creeped into this movie?

Comment: I'm confused. Are you talking about [Ian McKinley](https://final-destination-movie.fandom.com/wiki/Ian_McKinley) and [Wendy Christensen](https://final-destination-movie.fandom.com/wiki/Wendy_Christensen)? Because I don't remember McKinley causing Wendy's death. He tried to kill her, but he was unsuccessful. And iirc the fate of Wendy is unknown. Even if we consider she dies, her death is not caused by McKinley as he's already dead by that time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the original *Final Destination*, the whole latter part of the story is based around the concept "if you save the next person to die, death moves on then comes back later."

I don't know names because it has been years since I have watched it, but more than likely, since McKinley should have died but was saved, death moved on to the next victim (Wendy here apparently). Death will then come back to the person it missed in some other order (whether it be immediately next or after it has made a full round is debated between the first and second movie).

Out of universe though, it was probably just the writers sitting around wondering how to get the surprise and WOW factor out of the movie. Best way is to kill someone off unexpectedly.

Comment: Well I am saying that Death follows its plans. Then McKinley is already dead. How can he cause Wendy's Death? And If this is the case, THen does this mean that the photos that Wendy clicks at the amusement park are just clues and not definite indications?

Comment: Ok, I am missing something in your question then. I went back and watched the death scenes for each respective person you listed and can't find anything indicating that Mckinley caused Wendy's death. She may have thought he did because of the way the pictures turned out, but in the reality of the show, he is as susceptible as everyone else to death. As far as "Clues" to people's deaths, the meanings are very obscure and can be interpreted many ways, or just mean each photo taken was a person meant to die. In short, the photos aren't definite ways to tell people's death, just something for fans

Comment: Well, You see when Wendy says that in her Photo she is wearing the McKinley T-Shirt... She is actually coming to a conclusion by herself that maybe Ian will cause her death?!

Comment: That's probably just it. She was trying to figure out how and when she was going to die, not really noting there was a particular order or method to the deaths. When she tries to find a way that "Ian" is going to kill her, she ends up just causing a panic that essentially killed him instead of her, causing a bit of irony in the story line. All in all, any conclusions they came up with in the story were guesses and the photos were there to be interpreted by the viewer as well as the characters in the film. It created a good little  "how does that tie in" game for any moderate fan of the series.

Comment: yup exactly. this doubt had come to me when I saw the film for the second time. thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

I’m guessing the McKinley shirt she was wearing meant that her death would be caused by what killed Ian, the McKinley sign. But, Ian slowed her down and got in deaths path so Ian ended up getting killed by the sign instead of Wendy.